# Resources for making multi-perspective panoramic backgrounds?

Tags: animation

I've been scraping the internet for this topic in general for so long and it's reeeally hard to find a lot online even though it can be so prevalent in 2d animation. There's your basic banana pans and other panoramic/curvilinear layouts that seem very straightforward to tackle in my mind, even in something more complicated like this: https://twitter.com/fmod91/status/1328751781535387649?s=20&t=90CCxSE2Dgz1FBL1iS_oPw

BUT then there is deconstructing way more complex ones of a different nature like these:
https://twitter.com/JimZub/status/1330715701796102144?s=20 video
[image]

OR: https://twitter.com/kawakami_yu/status/1577932605173174272?t=d5M3lUShkk-2gsKi0w0Vig&s=19 video
[image]

Where THESE feel way more complex and harder to wrap my head around trying to set up or even grasp the theory on how and why it works so perfectly. Is there any resources that cover this topic and if so are there any parts that specifically address THESE types where the camera seems to be moving a lot more than just a simple "nodal" pan, and how to make them? It would be such an absolute godsend

Comment: Note that you can flag your own question and ask the mods to migrate it to Video Production Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Scott noted, but this is art related though, like would the people there exactly know how to address this? Because I only assumed to ask perspective questions here because this is where I've seen posts. say, a question on motion graphics animation, would they be asking a question in graphic design or video production, like

Comment: @turdmuncher Video is a specialized subset of design which uses software many **graphic** designers don't use - After Effects, Premier, etc. It's not about it being "art related". In the broad sense, I sit on a chair to design.. that doesn't make chair-related questions on topic. It's really about *where* you will get the **best answers**.  A stack *dedicated* to video and motion is certainly better for questions related to camera panning in animation. Because *that* is where users knowledgeable in such things will hang out.

Comment: @Scott sure enough